# Swipe View Pager Item on Button Click - Navigation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a list of view pager items, where in every row there are view pager items. I want to make the type of layout for a view pager item as shown in the image attached, where the user should be able to move the view pager using the arrow clicks too.

[image]

I am not able to get how to achieve the same, here is my code for the list adapter and pager adapter :

**ListView GetView**

```
 ViewHolder holder;
    if(rowView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item, parent,
                false);
        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mypager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.inner_layout_file, null);

TextView tv_view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
tv_view.setText("Example Item " + position);
((ViewPager) container).addView(layout);

});
return layout;
```

Pager Item Layout (inner_layout_file)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example Value"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**I am not able to get where to add the arrows and where to perform their on-clicks on runtime. I want to swipe the pager views using the arrows on the left and right**

Comment: Have you seen the example on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html. I believe it is about the same they achieve, just using tabs.

Comment: @cYrixmorten No, And dont want to see also. It is more complex and is not a solution for lower version too

Comment: @Raghunandan, Can you please help me in the same

Answer (score 1):

You should inflate the ViewPager within the ListView and set the Adapter for it there

This Is How you can do it...

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup vGroup) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vRow=view;
        final ContentHolder holder;
        if(view==null){
            holder=new ContentHolder();

                        //infalte your viewPager here

            vRow=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_swipe_view_pager, null);
            holder.vPager=(ViewPager) vRow.findViewById(R.id.ui_pager);
            holder.radiogrp=(RadioGroup) vRow.findViewById(R.id.ui_radiogroup);
            addRadio=new AddRadioViewSwipe(context, pageCount);
            addRadio.addRadio(holder.radiogrp);
            holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(0).setAlpha(1.0f);
            holder.vPager.setTag(R.id.ui_pager, "hold");
            vRow.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ContentHolder) vRow.getTag();
        }

        pagerAdpt=new ViewPagerAdapter(context, integer,R.layout.activity_viewpager_model);
        Parcelable state=holder.vPager.onSaveInstanceState();

                 //set your adapter here

        holder.vPager.setAdapter(pagerAdpt);

        holder.vPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(integer.length);
        holder.vPager.setTag(position);
        Float den = (float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        holder.vPager.setPageMargin((int) -den);
        holder.vPager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        holder.vPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for(int i=0;i<pageCount;i++){
                    holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(pageCount-(i+1)).setAlpha(0.5f);
                }                   
                holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(position).setAlpha(1.0f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        return vRow;
    }
```

Hope this could help you...

Comment: Thanks nit for the answer, Can I ask what is 'integer' here ??

Comment: Althugh the answer which you have replied is not as per my query

Comment: @Gaurav offcourse ...integer is an Array for my ViewPager images Integer integer[];

Comment: for setting button on either side you have do it into the ViewPager Layout

Comment: But I am not able to manage the list onitemclicks when i use view pager