# Adding More than one item in the list view row and navigate them

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I want to make the following layout in android. **(Image Attached)**

There is a list view and each item in the list view can has as many sub items. (One is visible in one row at a particular time), if a person wants to see further items in a particular row, then he has to use arrows provided on the left and right side of the item in the list view. **(Image Attached)**

On the arrow click, there should be a pager swiping type view and the next layout should come in the row.

I have tried so many approaches to do the same but have been stuck somewhere and have not been able to do the same yet:

Here I have tried all these :

[1st Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048248/maintaining-state-of-view-pager-item-in-the-list-view)

[2nd Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068084/swipe-view-pager-item-on-button-click-navigation)

[3rd Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159386/list-view-item-recycling)

[4th Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190367/adding-multiple-items-in-a-single-list-view-row)

**Can anyone please tell me how to do the same functionality as shown in the figure attached and discussed above**

[image]

Comment: Swype ListView? https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

Try this, this should work.

Solution 1:

1. Have Horizontal Scroll view as child in listview, so basically you have s child now with horizontal scroll ability
2. Add as many as children you want to this scroll views, you can easily adjust layout of childs within scroll view to display.

Solution 2:

1. Have a ViewFlipper as a child withing listview
2. Perform the same thing as above, add as many child you want within this flipper
3. With flipper you get easy hastle free option like which child you want to display by default withing flipper.

Hope it help.

Comment: Can you show me any good example related to the view flipper, I have never used View Flipper? Will it work with the arrow clicks ?

Comment: One thing more, the layouts in the scrollview are freely scrollable, which is not my requirement, I want to scroll one item at one time.
E.g when I press right arrow, the 2nd item in the row should come, and so on..

Comment: Yes flipper will work easily with arrows, you can easily control with them they have good APIS for switching views,

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

check this for reading about implementing viewflipper

Comment: Thanks @Techfist. I will try the same soon, and will let you know if it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Also, if scrolling freely is not  a requirement, then you can have a ViewGroup i.e any containers e.g LinearLayout/framelayout with arrows as button as child to listview, with this button you can control adding,revoming of child within them.

Comment: How I will be able to flip the view when I write all the things in the getView Method as shown in this link. Can you please see my get View
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190367/adding-multiple-items-in-a-single-list-view-row

Comment: Saw that couple of things, first do you have views in hand to put inside each row of listview, second are the number of views inside each row of listview fixes of variable?